# Need help on validating domains on the basis of ASCII and BASE64 encoded UTF-8 string

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am doing some tests related to ldap in java using **JDK 1.7**

I have configuration file from which I am reading value of one property like "dc=domain1,dc=com" to pass that later to ldap for searching operations.

Here I want to validate the value which is coming from properties file and that value should be only ASCII or Base64 encoded UTF-8 strings.

I have written following regex to validate the string but seems like it is having some issues.

here is my sample code:

```
public class ValidateDN {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String istr = "dc=domain1,dc=com";
        String myregex = "^dc=[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]*[,dc=[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]*]*";

        if (istr.matches(myregex)){
            System.out.println("String matches");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("String not matching");
        }

    }
}
```

It should pass all strings like:

```
dc=com
dc=domain1,dc=com
dc=domain2,dc=domain1,dc=com
```

It should fail for the values:

```
dc=domain1,dc=com,d
dc=domain1,dc=com,dc
```

(incomplete key or invalid syntax)

Can anyone suggest what should be done here to validate this properly?

Comment: it fails because com,dc has a , in the middle, right?

Comment: Yes, and it should fail... but this regex passes it and prints as "String matches"

Comment: Hm, I would go for a simpler solution. Split the string on commas `istr.split(",")` and then for each element of the array check if there's a string followed by `=`. Yes, it may take more time to execute but the maintenance is going to be much easier.

Comment: @AmitG, your code doesn't seem to do any ASCII checking or base64 validation

Comment: Can you guide me how I can do this checking efficiently?

Answer (score 2):

You have a major error in your regex - you're using square brackets instead of parenthesis. Square brackets mean: "Any character", not a sequence of characters.

Further, your regex can be simplified to:

```
(dc=[\w-]+,?)*
```

As LDAP DNs may contain spaces, you may want to consider using:

```
(\s*dc\s*=\s*[\w-]+\s*,?)*
```

Remember to escape the slashes as necessary when inserting into your code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem you are having is due to the structure of your regex.

Your regex:

```
"^dc=[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]*[,dc=[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]*]*"
```

has a flaw with the second character class. Specifically:

```
(`[,dc=[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]*]*.
```

It should be changed to `(,dc=[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]*)*` for the sake of having the literal `",dc="` match as well as the inner character class match.

The complete regex that should work is:

```
^dc=[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]*(,dc=[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\.]*)*
```